# how to unpublish content in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to unpublish the content created in drupal 7 which is created for specific content type.I have the content type 'testContentType'.I have many nodes for the content type.I want to unpublish the specific content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps:

- go to admin panel
- Click Find Content tab
- filter by Content Type
- Click the Edit button of the specific content
- Scroll down the Edit page and uncheck the Publish checkbox

If you don't understand I can show the screenshots. Let me know.

thanks

Comment: unpublished content displaying in home page

Comment: There is option promoted to front page. uncheck this option